# PHP Assistance with empty() in a loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Let's say I wanted to check to see if a variable is empty and then do something... I can do this:

```
if ( empty($phone) ) { $phone = 'Not Provided'; }
```

But I want to do that for a bunch of items. So I'm thinking an array and a loop, so something like this:

```
$optionalFieldsArray = array($phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip);

foreach ($optionalFieldsArray as $value) {
        //what goes here????
    }
```

Is this foreach a resonable way to do it, where I could check if $phone, $address, $city, etc. are empty and assign the "Not Provided" string to it when it is?

If so, can someone help me with the syntax that goes inside that loop?

Comment: this is easily googleable

Comment: Yeah, well, I didn't find a suitable answer. I guess you're just better than I am.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed their thoughts. Funny, there sure seemed to be a lot of opinions on how to accomplish this. Wish someone would upvote the question. Thanks, again, for everyone who contributed.

Comment: @SteveC. don't ask for upvotes, that's bad etiquette. The fact people didn't like your question is because they did not find it useful for the site or thought it didn't show research effort. Don't take that as a personal insult, there is a reason downvotes are only -2 while upvotes are +10.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Benjamin. I knew I was treading on questionable territory, but I guess I let emotions get involved. I just don't understand the mentality, considering there are millions of things here that I don't find useful, but I don't go downgrading people's reputation for it. A lack of research? I'm sorry people felt that way... I always research first, but I'm not a PHP expert so... what's easy for some may not be for others. :) Thank you, sincerely, though for reaching out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
<?php

$required_vars = array( 'phone', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip' );
foreach( $required_vars as $required_var ) {
    if( empty( $$required_var ) ) 
        $$required_var = 'Not Provided'; // $$var -> variable with name = value of $var 
}

?>
```

check the above code yourself. then only you can understand how it works. because it is confusing concept.

Comment: Why the variable variable?

Comment: he wants to check against some variables which are listed in given array. so we iterate through the array and check against the variable named current-array-element-value

Comment: one should check it by himself ( if don't know ). then only he can understand how it works. because it is confusing.

Comment: YES! This was the one! Thank you, Prakash... I understand now and the use of the $$.

Answer (score 3):

```
$optionalFieldsArray = array('phone'=>$phone, 'address'=>$address, 'city'=>$city, 'state'=>$state, 'zip'=>$zip);

foreach ($optionalFieldsArray as $key => $value) {
    if ( empty($value) ) { $optionalFieldsArray[$key] = 'Not Provided'; }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($optionalFieldsArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like -

```
$optionalFieldsArray = array($phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip);

foreach ($optionalFieldsArray as $key => $value) {
        if ( empty($optionalFieldsArray[$key]) ) { 
             $optionalFieldsArray[$key] = 'Not Provided'; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two code examples you provided, and use strings as keys in the optional array:

```
$optional = array(
    'phone'   => $phone,
    'address' => $address,
    'city'    => $city,
    'state'   => $state,
    'zip'     => $zip,
);
foreach ($optional as $type => $value) {
    if ($value == null) {
        echo "The {$type} field is empty!<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$optionalFieldsArray = array($phone, $address, $city, $state, $zip);

foreach($optionalFieldsArray as $k => $v) {
    // you could check for !empty here if you wanted too
    $optionalFieldsArray[$k] = empty($v) ? 'Not Provided' : $v;
 }

print_r($optionalFieldsArray);

Input Vars:
$phone = "1234567899";
$address = "";
$city = "";
$state = "";
$zip = "";
Output:
Array ( [0] => 1234567899 [1] => Not Provided [2] => Not Provided [3] => Not Provided [4] => Not Provided )
```